# Can't adjust the border

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my css. I can't adjust the green border and I want the green border to be smaller.

```css
.col_eight {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 29%;
  padding: -80px;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<a href="quicklinks.php">
  <div class="col_eight down">
    <div class="hover panel">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="box11">
          <p style="font-size:150%; color: white;">Quick Links</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

And here's a screenshot:

[Green Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx6fg.png)

Comment: Can you put the css and the html in the corresponding sections in the snippet

Comment: Hum, not relevant with no informations on how child component behave. Can you plese provide more code, better, a working example ? 
But so far, I'm not confident with your negative margin bottom. And just for your information, negative padding doesn't exist in css.

Comment: Watch out your child components, I bet one of them is messing your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try the border-width property in your css:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp

Comment: It only makes the border thicker or thinner, I want to adjust the size of the border. @nick tamburro

Comment: what do you mean by "size of the border"?

Comment: @curveball I want to make the green box smaller.

Comment: Oh, so then play with the width and height of the div? The border is just hugging the edge of your div, so adjust the size of that and the border will adjust too.

Comment: change `width` property then

Comment: I tried it only moves from left to right @curveball

Comment: So after you change the width, change the margin-left or margin-right

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want to make the space between your "Quick Links" button and the border smaller? If that's the case, you should look at your padding instead of your border.

Try giving the div a max-height to limit the stretch to the bottom. I can't help you if you don't provide the full HTML/CSS code.